# Absolute value of eigenvalues of a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let 
>   $$A =
> \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
> 1 & 1 & 1 \\
> 1 & w^2& w \\
> 1 & w & w^2
> \end{array} } \right]
> $$ 
>   where $w$ is a cube root of unity (other than 1). Let $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ denote the eigenvalues of $A^2$. Show that $|\lambda_1|+|\lambda_2|+|\lambda_3| \leq 9$.

**My Thoughts**: Elementary calculation shows that eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $3,3$ and $-3$. I don't understand why problem asks to show less or equal while it is exactly equal to 9. Am I missing something here? Are there some other ways to conclude this without doing computation? What does linear transformation $A$ represents here? My apology for some silly questions. Thank you!

Comment: It may be that the aim is to show this without getting to the eigenvalues of $A^2$...

Comment: @Martigan Can you suggest some other way?

Comment: I think the idea was to use the Gershgorin's lemma.

Answer (score 1):

This is the [discrete Fourier transform matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#The_unitary_DFT) of dimension $3$ (or a multiple of it). Its eigenvalues are in absolute value $\sqrt{3}$.

Your calculations seem OK.

Comment: Ok,But why problem asks to show that given quantity is less than/equal 9?